# My A-Frame scene doesn't render in Rift / Rift S / Quest Link when entering VR in Chrome

Tags: aframe

I'm using A-Frame 1.0.0 and [my basic scene](https://repl.it/@dmarcos/aframe) is not rendering in Chrome m79 when using an Oculus headset: Rift, Rift S or Quest via link.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

I click the enter VR button but I cannot see my content in headset. There are no errors in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do the following:

1. Make sure you are serving your content over `https` as it's enforced by the new WebXR standard.
2. Disable `XR device sandboxing` in chrome://flags
3. If the above doesn't work. In some laptops with NVidia cards Chrome might default to integrated graphics. Locate Chrome in `NVIDIA Control Panel` -> `Manage 3D Settings` -> `Program Settings` and select `High-performance NVIDIA processor` in the `Select the preferred graphics processor for this program` dropdown. Be aware that this option might cause Chrome to consume more battery.